# Attempting to implement an RNN on my dataframe dataset

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I'm curently trying to implement a RNN with my dataframe dataset. First I give you some details about this dataset. It's more than 300 000 lines with 13 columns. Each line is fulled by information about one team for one match of amateur basketball. So for one match we have 2 lines.
The main objective is to predict whether a team will win or lose its future match.

For all of this dataset we have temporality. This way we are able to know if a match was played before or after an other match.

I already succeed to implement basic prediction model like LinearRegression, Decision Tree or RN on this dataset.

But now my goal is to implement a RNN which will take into acount was happend for a specific team before this date.

First I want to implement a code which will take into account the lines before, in other words what happened before in previous matches.

Here is the code :

```
target_name = "win_bool"
y = data[target_name]
data = data.drop(columns=[target_name, "winner"])

print(y.shape)

X = data.iloc[:, :]

print(X.shape)

XTrain, XTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

scalar = StandardScaler()
XTrain = scalar.fit_transform(XTrain)
XTest = scalar.transform(XTest)

n_input = 16  # how many samples/rows/timesteps to look in the past in order to forecast the next sample
n_features = XTrain.shape[1]  # how many predictors/Xs/features we have to predict y
b_size = 32  # Number of timeseries samples in each batch
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(XTrain, yTrain, length=n_input, batch_size=b_size)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(150, activation="relu", input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")
model.summary()

model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=20)

loss_per_epoch = model.history.history["loss"]
plt.plot(range(len(loss_per_epoch)), loss_per_epoch)

test_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(
    XTest, np.zeros(len(XTest)), length=n_input, batch_size=b_size
)

y_pred = model.predict(test_generator)
results = pd.DataFrame({"y_true": yTest.values[n_input:], "y_pred": y_pred.ravel()})
print(results)

results.plot()
```

When I try to run this code I have this error message :

```
KeyError: 23

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/alexis/projet_pro_/BD_nv_vars_analyses_statistiques_modèles_correction.py", line 714, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=20)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1989, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1148, in fit
    steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1383, in get_data_handler
    return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1150, in __init__
    model=model)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 924, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 794, in __init__
    peek, x = self._peek_and_restore(x)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 928, in _peek_and_restore
    return x[0], x
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\sequence.py", line 374, in __getitem__
    targets = np.array([self.targets[row] for row in rows])
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\sequence.py", line 374, in <listcomp>
    targets = np.array([self.targets[row] for row in rows])
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 853, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 961, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 23
```

Will you be able to help me please ?

Comment: This [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe) will explain you how to use Dataframe in Keras sequential model. In the given link Dense layer is used. You can replace with LSTM/RNN layer.